# Is there a way in Amazon DynamoDB to implement MongoDB like aggregation pipeline.?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to migrate from MongoDB to DynamoDB , i need to implement MongoDB like aggregation pipeline in DynamoDB not sure how to implement in DynamoDB.
Below is my aggregation pipeline for MongoDB

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "$or": [
            {
              "attribute1": {
                "$regex": ".",
                "$options": "i"
              }
            },
            {
              "attribute2": {
                "$regex": ".",
                "$options": "i"
              }
            },

            {
              "_id": "."
            },
            {
              "attribute3": {
                "$regex": ".",
                "$options": "i"
              }
            },
            {
              "name": {
                "$regex": ".",
                "$options": "i"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "attribute4": "xyz"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "fields": "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "fields.createdDate": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$limit": 10
  }
])
```

Please suggest implementation approach for the above pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB is not suitable for aggregations. You'd need to query each item and aggregate programmatically. If it's small enough, it might work, but not recommended.

Try using AWS Athena or Redshift for aggregations. You can use Kinesis Firehose or Lambda to keep these DBs in sync with changes to Dynamo.